# How to force all treatments to have same intercept in lme4?

Tags: r, lme4

This is my first time posting here, so I hope my question isn't foolish, although I fear it has no answer.

I ran a feeding trial where I fed snails one of five different algae species, then measured individual length over time. I built a LMM using R's `lme4`:

```
model<-lmer(log(length)~treatment*day+(1+day|individual), data=real, REML=F)
```

In my model, one of the treatments has a very different intercept than the others:

[Plot of my model, showing the treatment with outlier intercept, and other treatments with roughly matching intercepts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXEIW.png)

I measured length 4 times over 61 days (day 7, 20, 42, 61), but unfortunately I didn't measure it on day 0. All of the snails came from the same batch, so each treatment had the same mean length at day 0. Is there any way to tell R that this is true, even if I don't know WHAT the mean length was on day 0? In theory, I could just adjust the intercepts so they match, but it seems that the slope of the line would also change if the model took into account this information.

I know that the model is written so that all the individuals have random intercepts. However, writing the model with the term `(0+day|individual)` so that individuals have fixed intercepts does not solve the problem, because the intercepts of individuals are the same only within treatments, but are different between treatments. It may be that I'm asking R to do the impossible or unethical, i.e. fabricate data.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Edit for a reproducible example:
The same problem happens if using the R "ChickWeights" dataset (these data are not a perfectly linear trend, but good enough as an example)

```
model.chix<-lmer(weight~Diet*Time+(Time|Chick), data=ChickWeight, REML=FALSE)

> summary(model.chix)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: weight ~ Diet * Time + (Time | Chick)
   Data: ChickWeight

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4824.2   4876.5  -2400.1   4800.2      566 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.7508 -0.5693 -0.0401  0.4694  3.5415 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 Chick    (Intercept) 103.61   10.179        
          Time         10.01    3.165   -0.99
 Residual             163.36   12.781        
Number of obs: 578, groups:  Chick, 50

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  33.6541     2.8023  12.009
Diet2        -5.0205     4.8072  -1.044
Diet3       -15.4038     4.8072  -3.204
Diet4        -1.7475     4.8145  -0.363
Time          6.2799     0.7304   8.598
Diet2:Time    2.3293     1.2508   1.862
Diet3:Time    5.1430     1.2508   4.112
Diet4:Time    3.2528     1.2515   2.599

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) Diet2  Diet3  Diet4  Time   Dt2:Tm Dt3:Tm
Diet2      -0.583                                          
Diet3      -0.583  0.340                                   
Diet4      -0.582  0.339  0.339                            
Time       -0.881  0.513  0.513  0.513                     
Diet2:Time  0.514 -0.882 -0.300 -0.299 -0.584              
Diet3:Time  0.514 -0.300 -0.882 -0.299 -0.584  0.341       
Diet4:Time  0.514 -0.300 -0.300 -0.882 -0.584  0.341  0.341
```

The intercept estimates predict chick weights at Day 0.  Chicks on Diet1 are predicted to weigh 33.7 g, while chicks on Diet3 are predicted to weigh 15.4 g less than that.  Wouldn't the model be a better fit if it forced all chick weights to be the same on Day 0, to match reality of the situation?

Comment: I might be wrong, but it looks like you have an AR1 model. See if this is helpful --> https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81246/unable-to-fit-repeated-measures-in-r/81255#81255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I can get matching intercepts by including the interaction term without the main effects term for treatment:

```
model.chix<-lmer(weight~Diet:Time+(Time|Chick), data=ChickWeight, REML=FALSE)
```

However, to include an interaction you must also include the main effects term, or else your statistics are wrong.  So, I settled on the model as written above and will make a case for its best fit of the existing data, if not of the intercept.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a reproducible example to understand this better?

What I get is that you want to remove random effects, right? In that case is

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)

model <- lmer(log(hwy) ~ -1 + displ + (displ || year), data=mpg, REML=F)
```

Comment: Removing random effects makes intercepts identical within treatments, but not between them.  I'm looking for a way to force the model to account for the fact that all treatments have the same starting weight for individuals in those treatments.  I tried your suggested code but it didn't make the intercepts match for all treatments.
See reproducible example in my edit above.  Thanks!